# How to configure Spring Boot as .war file together with security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I start my Spring Boot application by SpringBootServletInitializer class, because I would like to deploy it as .war file. I don't know how to enable security.

```
public class ApplicationInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Object[] configurations = {
            SecurityConfiguration.class,
            ApplicationInitializer.class
    };

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(configurations);
    }
}
```

where SecurityConfiguration is as follow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        /******/
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         /******/
    }
}
```

With this configuration I get AlreadyBuiltException:

```
'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
```

Comment: Try to load only the current class in `application.sources()` e.g. `return application.sources(ApplicationInitializer.class );` `SecurityConfiguration` will be component scanned if the application is structured correctly.

Comment: SecurityConfiguration is in the same package that ApplicationInitializer. But when I load only ApplicationInitializer, spring security is still in default mode (basic auth with one user and randomly generated password in console)

Comment: Do you have `@SpringBootApplication` on `ApplicationInitializer`?

Comment: Yes,but I found the solution.

Comment: What is the solution? Can you describe it, I am also having the same issue.

Comment: @Chalpat https://stackoverflow.com/a/38719277/4809490

Answer (score 1):

Use **`@EnableGlobalAuthentication`** for indicating that class can be used to configure a global instance of **`AuthenticationManagerBuilder`**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {  
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       //       
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
        //                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in SecurityConfiguration instead of:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    /******/
}
```

should be:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by excluding the embedded tomcat artifact from your app pom definition just like so:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Afterwards you can move on to your Application "setup" and do the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        return application.sources(ApplicationInitializer.class);
    }

   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This way you take leverage of Spring Framework’s Servlet 3.0 support and you can configure the application when it is launched by the servlet container.

Oh... and don't forget to change your app packaging in pom.xml, just like so:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

For security... just @EnableWebSecurity in your configuration class.